# Как в результате запроса к базе получить строку с разделителем?

Tags: c#, sqlite, ado.net

Имею базу sqlite , к ней в методе делаю запрос, и не могу сообразить как мне правильно вернуть строку с разделителем.

```
 public string GetImportedFileList(string connstring, string idrecord,string tablename,string Idname)
    {
        string ImportedFiles = null;
        using (SQLiteConnection connect = new SQLiteConnection(connstring))
        {
            connect.Open();
            using (SQLiteCommand fmd = connect.CreateCommand())
            {
                var sb= new StringBuilder();
                var que = sb.Append("SELECT * FROM "+tablename+" where "+Idname+"="+idrecord);


                fmd.CommandText = que.ToString();
                fmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                SQLiteDataReader r = fmd.ExecuteReader();


                while (r.Read())
                {
                    object[] values = new object[] { };
                    r.GetValues(values);
                    ImportedFiles= String.Join(",", values).ToString();
                }
            }
        }
        return ImportedFiles;
    }
```

На вход метода подаю строку подключения, имя таблицы, имя нужного мне поля, и значение этого поля. И на выходе хочется увидеть результат запроса в виде строки с разделителем.

Строка всегда будет одна, так как id уникален в базе. Хочу получить в строке значения всех столбцов через запятую или другой разделитель.

Comment: Приведите пример вызова метода и строки, которая должна получиться. Там всегда будет одна строка и Вы ходите вернуть значения всех столбцов через запятую? Или там всегда будет один столбец и нужно вернуть значения всех строк? Или много столбцов и строк и все нужно через разделитель?

Comment: @defaultlocale Спасибо за ответ , да я хочу получить в строке значения всех столбцов через запятую или другой разделитель

Comment: А если будет несколько строк?

Comment: @defaultlocale всегда будет одна строка, так как id уникален в базе

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно получить значения всех столбцов через [`GetValues`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.data.sqlite.sqlitedatareader.getvalues?view=msdata-sqlite-2.0.0#Microsoft_Data_Sqlite_SqliteDataReader_GetValues_System_Object___) и соединить их через [`String.Join`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netframework-4.8):

```
...
while (r.Read())
{
    object[] values = new object[r.FieldCount];
    r.GetValues(values);
    return String.Join(",", values);
}
...
```

Все значения будут считаны как `object` и преобразованы в строку через `ToString()` по-умолчанию. Если потребуется выводить в каком-то особенном строковом представлении, то придется выбирать значения циклом по одному через [`GetValue`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.data.sqlite.sqlitedatareader.getvalue?view=msdata-sqlite-2.0.0#Microsoft_Data_Sqlite_SqliteDataReader_GetValue_System_Int32_).

Советую добавить проверку на то, что запрос вернул ровно одну строку, во избежание недоразумений.

Еще, обычно при составлении запросов через конкатенацию строк советуют изучить работу с параметризованными запросами, чтобы избежать SQL-инъекции. Но в данном случае запрос имеет динамическую структуру и параметризовать получится только разве что `idrecord`. В любом случае подумайте о безопасности если какой-то аргументов метода приходит извне.

Comment: Увы не сработало, пустая строка получается, в вопросе обновил код

Comment: @VladimrVladimirovoch Прошу прощения, забыл проинициализировать массив. Обновил ответ, попробуйте еще раз.

Comment: Спасибо заработало